# How to translate an Angular Bootstrap UI modal in a Django app

Tags: angularjs, django, internationalization, angular-ui-bootstrap

There's an application written in Django 1.8 where some modals are displayed with `angular.js` using [UI Bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/).

I would like to add translations to this modal, however while adding django translations tags, e.g. `{% load i18x %}`, `{% trans 'some text'%}`, etc., into the modal they are not interpreted by Django and simply displayed as text.

Is there something I need to do before I get this working *the Django way of doing it*, or should I approach translations in this UI Bootstrap modal in a angular.js way? It the latter is true - how to do it?

Translations outside of this modal are working fine...

Comment: Django's template syntax is for, well, templates. They won't work inside any javascript file, look in the docs for translating javascript files.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! You're fully correct - I have moved to managed the translations from the javascript side. Thanks for your hint!